# Additional parameters using interfaces methods in PHP 5

Tags: php, oop, interface, php-5.6, abstract-methods

I have a question, can a method from an interface get additional parameters during the implementation like an abstract method? for example:

```
<?php

interface Figures {

    public function setColor($color);
}

class Circle implements Figures {

    public function setColor($color, $additional_parameter, ...) {

    }
}
```

?>

Comment: [You could've answered this yourself so quickly](https://eval.in/416074)

Comment: @RobbieAverill thank you, I didn't know about that site, cool :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it will give you an error like this

```
Fatal error: Declaration of Circle::setColor() must be compatible with Figures::setColor($color)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this as long as you make the additional parameters optional:

```
public function setColor($color, $additional_parameter = "defaultvalue", $another_parameter = null) { ...
```

Still **it's not the best idea** as it will be hard to use your code in a predictable way, as sometimes your argument will be just ignored. It's also bad practice not to follow the interface definition strictly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

Re your question: [no.](https://eval.in/416074)

An interface is supposed to provide a "contract" that all children must adhere to. As such, it might not be a good idea to break that contract by doing extra things anyway.

An alternative option is to provide a public setter for the additional parameters, then access them by properties within `setColor()`:

```
interface Figures {

    public function setColor($color);
}

class Circle implements Figures {
    protected $_additionalParameter;

    public function setColor($color) {
        echo $this->_additionalParameter . ' - not passed in any more';
    }

    public function setAdditionalParameter($blah = '')
    {
        $this->_additionalParameter = $blah;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

And used like so:

```
// you implement stuff
$circle = new Circle;
$circle->setAdditionalParameter('blah')
       ->setColor('color');
// blah - not passed in any more
```

If you have lots of additional parameters you might find it tidier to use the [magic method `__set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set) to cover all your bases instead of loading up your classes with lots of them.